# c# webBrowser select dropdown value on before label

Tags: c#, select, drop-down-menu, browser, label

I'm on coding a programm and need your help.

Dropdown from one dropdownBox can I select, but I want to do it like RoboForm:

"Fieldname:" your job situation
"content:" farmer

Und dann selected er in egal welcher Box, die neben/über (über im Source) die Label ist, den Inhalt.

Then he should selected in whatever box that next to / over (over the source), the label is the content.

Thus, how I find the corresponding box under the label?

```
<label>your job situation</label>
<div class="w_bg_input EmploymentSelect longregistration"> 
<select tabindex="21"> 
<option value="-1"> Auswählen</option>
<option value="2796310"> farmer</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

greets,
Bl1zz4rD

Comment: you question is not clear.do you want to select an item in list automatically with webbrowser?

Comment: Ah yes, I was just confused from RoboForm because of the Label.
But now where you say, I just need to read all Values in the dropdown and select the one.

But how can I read all the values in the dropdown?